# Reading date and time from a text file using powershell Get-Content

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a text file which contains the last update of a Log file.

```
 Volume in drive E is ISCSI
 Volume Serial Number is XXXXXX

 Directory of E:\Apps\LOGS

02/26/2020  11:39 AM           762,661-vx_02262020.log
               1 File(s)        762,661 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  12,554,166,272 bytes free
```

I am using the below powershell script to read the content and email the same:

```
$Date = (Get-Date -format "MMddyyyy")

$body = Get-Content -path C:\Desktop\Logs\LOG_TIME_$Date.txt -raw

Send-MailMessage -To "abc@gmail.com2" -From "abc@gmail.com"  -Subject "LOG TIME $Date" -Body "$body" -SmtpServer "xxxxx.main.glb.corp.local"
```

The code works fine and sends all the content of the files in the body to my email. But i only want the date and time (which will keep changing) to be sent in the email.

I have tried lot of options, but none of which seems to work:

- used | select-string "05/"
- used Where-Object
- used -Pattern '$Date' -AllMatches |

Can someone help me how to populate only date and time in the email body from the text file  ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this some more please? What is the desired body for the email? Only Date and Time read from the log file, or??  P.S. You should not use curly quotes `“` and `”` in code. This may look nice in a word document, but can create weird errors in code. Replace them with straight quotes `"`

Comment: Thank you Theo for the comments. Changes done and statement elaborated. 
Yes - I just need the date and time from text file to appear in the email body. The date and time will keep on changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse out the date and time in the file, you could use this:

```
$Date = (Get-Date -format "MMddyyyy")

$content = Get-Content -Path "C:\Desktop\Logs\LOG_TIME_$Date.txt" -Raw
if ($content -match '(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s+[AP]M)') {
    $dateString = $matches[1] -replace '\s+', ' '
    $dateInFile = [DateTime]::ParseExact($dateString, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt', [cultureinfo]'en-UK')
}

$mailParams = @{
    To         = "abc@gmail.com"
    From       = "abc@gmail.com"
    Subject    = "LOG TIME $Date"
    Body       = $dateInFile
    SmtpServer = "xxxxx.main.glb.corp.local"
}

Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

Regex details:

> ```
> (             # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
>    \d         # Match a single digit 0..9
>       {2}     # Exactly 2 times
>    /          # Match the character "/" literally
>    \d         # Match a single digit 0..9
>       {2}     # Exactly 2 times
>    /          # Match the character "/" literally
>    \d         # Match a single digit 0..9
>       {4}     # Exactly 4 times
>    \s         # Match a single character that is a "whitespace character" (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>       +       # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    \d         # Match a single digit 0..9
>       {1,2}   # Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    :          # Match the character ":" literally
>    \d         # Match a single digit 0..9
>       {2}     # Exactly 2 times
>    \s         # Match a single character that is a "whitespace character" (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>       +       # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    [AP]       # Match a single character present in the list "AP"
>    M          # Match the character "M" literally
> )
> ```

Comment: Perfect Theo. The solution works correctly, but i do not get AM and PM.The output is just date and time: "02/26/2020 11:39:00" - Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnkitDalal The format of the date in the email can be anyway you like. At the moment, it is simply using the `.ToString()` format as set in your local machine, but you can add your own format, either using [Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or [Custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)  format strings.

Comment: @AnkitDalal  If you are fine with the format as parsed from the file (`MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt`), you could even comment out the line where the date is parsed into a [DateTime] object and set the `$dateString` in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Easy done with regex:

```
$date = $content | ? { $_ -match '(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4})' } | % { $_ -replace '^(.*)(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4})(.*)$', '$2' }
```

Comment: Where do i place it in the code ? It doesn't seem to work.